# RabbitMQ and IoT device: keep queue open?

Tags: rabbitmq

We're using RabbitMQ in a new project.  We'll have IoT devices communicating with queues.

For the devices to send info to the cloud we don't see any issues, however sometimes we need to deliver messages from our backend to the IoT devices.  For this we let the devices open an exclusive queue. This works perfectly, as long as the devices are online.  When they aren't, the queue is closed and no messages can be send to it anymore.

Is there a way to keep the queue open, so messages are kept until the IoT device comes back online?

Vice-versa: Is there some way to have guaranteed delivery starting at the IoT device.  For example: energy measurements every 15 minutes. If the connection drops, messages should be stored on disk (to prevent message loss in case of power cut). They are sent later on when the connection comes back online.  Does a service or client library exist that implements this or do we need to develop this ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep the queue open, so messages are kept until the
> IoT device comes back online?

Use a regular queue, and make sure it's durable if you'd like it to survive RabbitMQ restarts.

> Is there some way to have guaranteed delivery starting at the IoT
> device.

That depends on the library you are using, but you don't tell us what library nor what protocol you're using (AMQP vs MQTT, for instance).

Some libraries offer automatic reconnect and re-creation of topology (queues, exchanges, etc) but I'm not aware of any that offer local storage of messages until the broker is available again. You'll have to code that yourself.

Please carefully read the documentation with regard to publisher confirmations and consumer acknowledgements, as those are both necessary for reliable messaging [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html).

Comment: Thanks.  We use AMQP.  The IoT devices are connected through 4G to the cloud.  So there aren't any libraries that cache the requests to the Queue locally on the IoT device if the connection to the RabbitMQ server can't be made?  This to me would seem like a problem that many developers would face?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not aware of any libraries that do that for you. Since an AMQP message body is just a sequence of bytes, writing that data to local durable storage prior to sending the message and deleting it after getting the publisher confirmation shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Our Cloud has several exchanges and credentials called CredentialsBucket assigned to a set of IoT devices. When an IoT device register, we provide them this credentials that includes a durable queue and exchange. When the IoT device push messages, it goes to Cloud through the exchange where we do additional security check using HMAC.
When Cloud send a message, it send it directly to his queue (no persistent messages in our case) and the IoT device do the same kind of security check.